# Dynamics CRM adds unnecessary "undefined" as part of src image in Social Pane when you add an post

Tags: dynamics-crm

I put social pane on my form and when I press "add post" it adds a new one with an image of user with corrupted path to img src.

[image: wrong src path]

`<img class="ef5505c7-2e73-e511-9457-0050569749e7" alt="Avatar" src="/myorganization/undefined/WebResources//msdyn_/Images/default_user_image_small.png?ver=-35756626">`

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a super quick and dirty fix but it should theoretically work.  The new source does the same thing that the corrupted one would had it not been corrupted in the first place.  Also take into consideration, this is assuming the corrupted URL is the same for all users with default user images.  While I don't recommend this as a permanent fix, I figured I'd be the first to offer at least an option.

```js
//Run on FormLoad
function FixImageSrc() {
  //Get all images with corrupted src
  $("img[src$='/myorganization/undefined/WebResources//msdyn_/Images/default_user_image_small.png?ver=-35756626']").each() {      
    //Assign new src to each image
    $(this).attr("src", "/myorganization/WebResources/msdyn_/Images/default_user_image_small.png");        
  }
}
```